# How to calculate probability of an event happening X times in Y attempts

Tags: probability

I have an event that has 25% chance of occurring per attempt. There are X possible attempts. I want to calculate the probability of the event happening Y times.

Adding probabilities does not seems to make sense. It has a 25% chance of hitting in one attempt. But it doesn't have a 100% probability of happening in 4 attempts. It seems like that chance is actually 1-(.75 ^ 4) = 68.4% chance of happening.

But then I am completely lost as to how to calculate the chances that the event could happen 2 or 3 times in X attempts.

Comment: Trusting that the various trials are independent, this is just a standard question about the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

Comment: @lulu Thank you, that is very helpful.  Would you happen to be able to know which of these functions would give me x>=k? http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Statistics_Distributions_Univariate_BinomialDistribution.htm I can't seem to find the combination that gives me something reasonable.  I'm trying to match values from https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx where for n=4 the probability of x >=1 is .68

Comment: For $n=4$, the probability that $X≥1$ is $1-P(X=0)=1-\left(\frac 34\right)^4=\frac {175}{256}\approx .68359$